# Custom function losing return variable value

Tags: php

I have a custom function which is meant to return certain values on successful completion. In short, the relevant section looks like this:

```
function register($email, $username, $password)
{
....
$return = array();
$return['code'] = 4;
$return['email'] = $email;
var_dump($return);
echo "<h1>SUCCESS</h1>";
return $return;
}
```

I can confirm the function does actually reach this stage, because just above the code posted is a SQL query which successfully adds a row to the database and I can also see the 'SUCCESS' message gets posted.

The var_dump inside the function returns the following:

```
array (size=2)
'code' => int 4
'email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=13)
```

So far, so good. However, if I then go and actually call this function $return is empty. For example, if I do this:

```
register($email, $username, $password);
var_dump($return);
echo "<h1>Return code & email: $return & ".$return['code']." ".$return['email']."</h1>";
```

The function runs successfully, a new user is registered and I see 'SUCCESS', but I don't get the $return array returned. var_dump returns this:

```
string '' (length=0)
```

And calls to $return['code'] and $return['email'] are met with Warning: Illegal string offset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your calling method to the function is incorrect, do it as any of the three answers (by Mathew Mc govern, Tim Helge or Dom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the function and returning a value, but you're not grabbing the return value.

`$return = register($email, $username, $password);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the return value to a variable:

```
$register = register($email, $username, $password);
```

`return $register` doesn't mean that the function will create a variable `$register` in the calling scope, but rather that it will return the content of `$register` to the calling scope, which then has to figure out what to do with it, e.g. assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You must do `$return = register($email, $username, $password);`

Answer (score 1):

the mistake is when you call your function:

```
register($email, username, password);
```

thinks will be better if you do:

```
$return = register($email, $username, $password);
```